# How to read/write FPSCR on Cortex-A9?

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, neon

I'm working on a ARM Cortex-A9 based system running software that uses nested interrupts; however, the method for implementing nested interrupts seems to be flawed as floating-point values and operations can get corrupted.

To mitigate this I'm trying to save the states of the floating-point registers when entering an interrupting routine. The method I'm trying for FPSCR is this:

```
asm ("VMRS %0, FPSCR " : "=r" ( savedReg)); //Save

asm ("VMSR FPSCR, %0 " : "=r" ( savedReg)); //Restore
```

The read seems to work but not the write, it causes the A9 to reboot.

Is it possible to access the FPSCR in this way? What other method is recomended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing an undefined value to FPSCR and savedReg. You want:

```
asm volatile ("VMSR FPSCR, %0 " : : "r" ( savedReg)); //Restore
```

Also there is no guarantee that the floating point operations stay between the inline assembler (though `volatile` and `"memory"` may help), use standalone assembler.

Comment: oh, so the problem was with the GCC assembler, not the ARM instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as known to me,  modifying the coprocessors is allowed only in the supervisor mode.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say here, but writing the FPSCR is definitely allowed in user mode.  It is, for example, the way to reset the cumulative exception flags, or change rounding mode - things which you can do from standard C code via <fenv.h>.

Answer (score 0):

I use a linux kernel module to run assembly code to give user mode access to interesting coprocessor registers on load.  This is only useful for experiments/diagnostics, obviously not in shipping code.

Comment: I'm not running Linux or any other OS, just a "bare-metal" application. I should already be in supervisor mode, right?

Comment: Once in user mode, the only way switching back is through exceptions, and exception handlers can be set in supervisor mode. Which means, you'll have to modify the boot code.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see any reason executing something in supervisor mode once the initial setup is done.